# Ajax Dropdown loading by preselected dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two page and each page have one form

***Page 1-Form A)***

One dropdown (Value populating from database) and button to continue

```
<select name="form[formA][]" id="dropdown1">
        <option value="1">Option 01</option>
        <option value="1">Option 02</option>
</select>
<button>CONTINUE</button>
```

***Page 2-Form B)***

Same dropdown in form a + second dropdown (values loading by Ajax based on dropdown A selection)

```
 <select name="form[formA][]" id="dropdown1">
        <option value="1">Option 01</option>
        <option value="1">Option 02</option>
</select>
 <select name="form[formB][]" id="dropdown2">
        <option value="1">Option 01</option>
        <option value="">Please select from dropdown1</option>
</select>
```

**Now the problem!,**
From Page1 by pressing continue, I’ll pass dropdown value to page 2 with below code

```
url/page2?form[formA][]={dropdown1:value}
```

Then on page 2 my first dropdown is auto selected, but second dropdown (ajax) is not loading.

```
dropdown1_id.on('change',  function(e) {
    var selectvalue = $(this).val();
    //Display 'loading' status in the target select list
    dropdown2_id.html('<option value="">Loading...</option>');
    if (selectvalue == '') 
    {
        dropdown2_id.html(initial_dropdown2_html);
    } 
    else 
    {
        //Make AJAX request, using the selected value as the GET
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            data:'option=com_mycomponent&task=getdropdown2sHTML&fvalue='+selectvalue,
            success: function(output) {
                dropdown2_id.html(output);
                updateSelect(dropdown2_id.val());
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status +  ' ' + thrownError);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

On Form B - page 2 Dropdowns without direction form page1 and by itself are working fine.

Comment: Is there an actual reason you're going from `page1` to `page2` instead of just using JavaScript all the way in the first place to show/generate/populate your second dropdown

Comment: @Thernys Considering page1 as home page with one dropdown and button only and page2 as different page which the actual form is there. Lets say page1 is short form of page2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `change` event is not fired for programmatic changes of a `select`'s value.

> The change event is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>` elements when a change to the element's value is **committed by the user**. ([Change event on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change))

Assuming `dropdown1_id` is a valid jQuery collection, you should then place the following somewhere after you have attached the `change` listener. Mind your placement, so the change listener will only be forced to run **once**, on page load.

```
dropdown1_id.trigger('change');
```

Here is a [simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2mjunph4/) to demonstrate.

Comment: @allogos I believe I understood you just fine. Please try my suggestion. To put it into the terms of the actual Page2 you linked, add `Building_id.trigger('change');` as the last line of your `$(document).ready()` callback.

Comment: Supper, Worked. Thanks